# Error in passing an element of vector of structures to pthread_create()

Tags: c++, vector, pthreads

I have to create a vector of structures and pass a structure element as the first argument of pthread_create() function.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
struct example
{
int myint;
pthread_t thread;
};

int main()
{
.............
vector<example> obj;
int count = 1;
while(count < n)
{
int *thread_id = new int(count);                  
pthread_create(&(obj[count].thread), NULL, worker_routine, thread_id);
count = count+1;
........................
.........................
    }
}
```

I have only included the parts of code that I think has triggered the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7629e4f in __pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=<optimized out>, attr=<optimized out>, 
start_routine=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:631
631 pthread_create.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Your `obj` has zero elements. Do you resize it before you pass in a pointer to arbitrary elements in it?

Comment: Any reason you're using `pthread` instead of the `thread` standard library?

Comment: @MikeVine, I have not resized obj. I am new to using vectors and don't know if I am doing it right. But generally, with arrays, I can pass it as follows:  examples = new example[N]; While(){.........pthread_create(&(examples[count].thread), NULL, worker_routine, thread_id);}

Comment: @Holt, I have to use pthread library only (part of the assignment)

Comment: It is also *extremely unusual* to create a single integer with `new int(count)`. Fixing compiler errors by *guessing* the language is not the way to learn C++.

Comment: @BoPersson, can you guide me how I should pass the structure element to avoid fixing compiler errors?

Comment: @jerry - You might want to reread the part on pointers in your C++ book. `new int(count)` is perhaps inventive, but really odd when you can pass a pointer parameter using `&count`.

Comment: @Bo Persson, Problem is not really around what you are suggesting (May be you are right, but it works fine with the array implementation. For now I want to use vectors which led to this problem). If possible please suggest regarding passing the vector's struct element.

Comment: The thing is that `new int(count)` isn't even an array, it is a single int on the heap with the value `count`. That's why it is odd. An array would be `new int[count]`. Anyway, if you want a vector with `n` objects you can just do `vector<example> obj(n);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with vector. Because in the vector you did not add any element and you are trying to access like below.

```
obj[count].thread //obj does not have any element
```

Make changes like below:-

```
struct example e1, e2, e3,e4,e5;
obj.push_back(e1);
obj.push_back(e2);
obj.push_back(e3);
obj.push_back(e4);
obj.push_back(e5);

while(count < 5)
{
     int *thread_id = new int(count);                  
     pthread_create(&(obj[count].thread), NULL, worker_routine, thread_id);
     struct example e;
     obj.push_back(e);
```

One more option:-
    struct example e1;
    vector obj(e1);
    int count = 1;
    while(count < n)
    {
      int *thread_id = new int(count);
      pthread_create(&(obj[count].thread), NULL, worker_routine, thread_id);

Better use C++ style of multi threading it is much easier:-

```
struct example
{
   int myint;

  void operator()()
  {
      std::cout<<"I am thread :"<<myint<<std::endl;     
  }       
};

int main()
{
   struct example exmp;
   exmp.myint = 1;
   std::thread t1(exmp);
   t1.join();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BoPersson, Please see my modified answer.

Comment: While using an array, I don't have to push an array element before passing it through the pthread_create() function. Do vectors work differently in such a case?

Comment: Can not say as I did not see your array declaration. Just follow my example and try to run it.

Comment: I can't push_back it before the pthread_create() call!!.. If possible please suggest some other way. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @jerry, I have modified my answer. Go for 2nd option. If it fix your issue please do not forget to accept my answer.